# Why a constructor is called twice when an object is instantiated

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

Per my understanding, I know that when an object is instantiated, a constructor is called once. But I can't understand why both constructors are called and only one object is instantiated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define print(me) cout << me << endl;

class A 
{
    public:
    A() { print("default called"); }
    A(int x) { print("paramterized called"); }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a = A(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I got output:
default called
parameterized called

Comment: `A a;` calls the default constructor.

Comment: `A a;` doesn't specify a constructor, so the default one (the one with no arguments) are called.

Comment: You should print the value of `this` instead of just the message.  Then you will realize that the constructors are being called for different objects, not the same object.  But with that ill-advised `print` macro, you can't do it.  Just use `std::cout` directly in the constructor, and not obfuscate the code with macros like `print`.

Comment: Works completely as expected! Constructor 1 : A a; Constructor two A(10);

Comment: if you provide a printing assignment operator you will see that it is called as well

Comment: @infinitezero: That's not exactly true. `A a = A();` requires an accessible copy constructor , since it conceptually is a copy of the temporary `A()` to be used in the construction of  `A a;`. `A a;` **is** the same as `A a{ };`

Comment: @MSalters while technically true, in all my tests only the default constructor gets called, probably because it is optimised out.

Comment: @infinitezero: That's called copy elision. it is a different part of the compiler, so it still matters that the copy constructor is not deleted. With a deleted copy ctor, the part of the compiler that optimizes it doesn't even get to run.

Answer (score 5):

In these lines

```
A a;
a = A(10);
```

there are created two objects of the type A. The first one is created in the declaration using the default constructor

```
A a;
```

And the second one is a temporary object created in the expression A( 10 )

```
a = A(10);
```

that then is assigned using the copy assignment operator to the already existent object `a`.

Due to the copy elision you could avoid the use of the default constructor by writing initially

```
A a = A( 10 );
```

In fact due to the copy elision it is equivalent to

```
A a( 10 );
```

provided that the copy constructor is not declared as explicit.

Comment: _"provided that the copy constructor is not declared as explicit"_ I don't see why it should be an issue. We are not doing any implicit conversion here, just calling the constructor [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/84MWY96vq)

Comment: @Fareanor In this declaration A a = A( 10 ); the copy constructor shall not be explicit at least in C++ 14.

Comment: Oh right, but you mentioned it below the `A a(10);` syntax hence my confusion. Because there is no problem, even in C++14 to use the original syntax `A a(10);` no matter if the copy ctor is `explicit` or not (since the copy ctor is not involved here)

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow, thanks dude, but I cannot understand exactly what do you mean by "there are created two objects of the type A" since I just have one instance "a"!

Comment: @AccessDenied In this expression A( 10 ) there is created a temporary object of the type A.

Answer (score 0):

You are also calling function while creating it with A a;

You can solve it by initializing value while creating it like this:

```
int main()
{
    A a = A(10); 
}
```

Or as a Fareanor said :

```
 int main()
    {
        A a(10);
    }
```